# Creating html report, can I create edit links to local files?

Tags: python, html, pytest

I would like to convert py.test reports that look like this:

```
self = <test_testcenter_views.TestSiteViews testMethod=test_testcenter>

    def test_testcenter(self):
        "Test the tctr_update view."
>       r = self.client.get('/admin/cms/testcenter/442/')

..\..\..\admin\cms\tests\test_testcenter_views.py:27: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
...
```

into something that's easier to grok and navigate (and hopefully easy to generate).  I would like to add expand/collapse of stack frames, minimal syntax highlighting, "go-to-definition" links, and hopefully I could turn the path to the file into a link that would open the file in the default editor for .py files.

I've tried to search google for solution to creating a link to a local file, that will open it in a local editor, but all I've found is answers involving web-servers.  Since the report will be opened by the user double-clicking on the report, there shouldn't be any security issues..?

Perhaps I should be using something other than html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think a simple a-tag with href="file:///..." should work at least for showing it. Editing is a different matter and may need configuration of the browser or an extension.